# (typeorm-postgresql) How to access transactional entity manager globally

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

is there a way to run a query inside a transaction block without using the provided transactional manager? For some reasons, I will need to execute query inside a queue which is using third party storage like redis, in this case, I cannot pass the transactional entity manager into the queue function. Thanks if you can give me some advices!